# Memory consumption of Chrome in Ubuntu constantly increases

Tags: google-chrome

I have laptop with 8Gb of memory. If I start Ubuntu 14.04 freshly and open Chrome with ~20 tabs (that's my regular usage) and Skype it consumes around 2.3Gb of memory, which is perfect for me.

Now with time (usually in some days) that memory usage increases, and it becomes 5-6Gb with same amount of Chrome tabs without any additional programs opened.

I noticed same behavior from Chrome on Windows 8 when I was using it quite some time ago, so are you guys having same problem with Chrome?

Is it possible to fix it somehow for not consuming so much memory, without restarting laptop every day? Because logically thinking, if 2.3Gb of Ram is enough now, why would it need +3 or +4Gb additional after few days?

Comment: Just to check, you kept Chrome open for several days, without closing it? If so, there's probably a small memory leak somewhere (which wouldn't surprise me, since this happens frequently in C/C++ programming, and Chrome isn't designed to run for several days straight).

Comment: @saiarcot895 yes, I restart computer once a week, either due to updates, or for a reason with memory, and all that time Chrome is open.

Comment: Can you instead consider closing Chrome frequently (once every two days, maybe) and reopening it? Then, you won't be restarting the laptop.

Comment: I think it does not help. As far as I remember it does not help, but I will test it soon and upadate here :)

Comment: You should probably report the issue to Google. Chrome is a proprietary browser and memory leaks are bugs. Nobody in the Ubuntu community can fix Chrome bugs. Only Google can do so.

Comment: I have had the exact same problem with chrome on several releases, it is not something else. I have had my computer just freeze when chrome is open with 5 tabs, but the same computer is fine with chrome closed from boot. For restarting chrome, you might need to do more than just close the window, as by default chrome runs in the background. It should show up in the notifications, at least it does for me in kde. Right click on the chrome icon and deselect "let chrome run in the background".

Comment: actually, open chrome settings and deselect "continue running background apps when google chrome is closed" under the system settings part

Comment: @sbergeron ok, I deselected that. I will update on how it goes :)

Comment: good luck, I just use firefox when I'm opening a bunch of tabs